# Why does my iOS method return the week of the year as 1 and not 53?

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

```
-(NSInteger)getTheUltimateWeekOfAYear:(NSInteger)year
{
    NSDateComponents *comps = [NSDateComponents alloc];
    [comps setDay:31];
    [comps setMonth:12];
    [comps  setYear:year];

    NSCalendar *usersCalendar =[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleCalendar];
    NSDate *date = [usersCalendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    NSDateComponents *weekComps =
    [usersCalendar components:NSWeekCalendarUnit fromDate:date];

    return [weekComps week];
}
```

`

Hi, 
This snippet wrongly return 1 when run on the iOS 5.1 Simulator. I believe it should return 53. What am I doing wrong? BTW my Simulator is preset to gregorian calendar.
/John

Comment: It depends on your context: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering

Comment: @rene: It is correct answer for this question. can you post this as answer ?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your context. From the wikipedia:

ISO 8601 includes the ISO week date system, a numbering system for weeks – each week begins on a Monday and is associated with the year that contains that week's Thursday (so that if a year starts in a long weekend Friday–Sunday, week number one of the year will start after that). For example, week 1 of 2004 (2004W01) ran from Monday 29 December 2003 to Sunday, 4 January 2004, because its Thursday was 1 January 2004, whereas week 1 of 2005 (2005W01) ran from Monday 3 January 2005 to Sunday 9 January 2005, because its Thursday was 6 January 2005 and so the first Thursday of 2005. The highest week number in a year is either 52 or 53 (it was 53 in the year 2004).

In some countries, though, the numbering system is different from the ISO standard.

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-day_week#Week_numbering)

Comment: Thank you for this answer and thanks for enlighten me. Now, I wonder should I change4 my code to get the method to be right in every country?